# How can I do a presence check with firebase realtime database in Unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, user-presence

Good day, I am using Firebase with Unity for my recent game, and I want to be able to display to a player if other players are online or offline? Please, how do I implement this in Unity? Thank you.

Comment: add IST timestamb to database by each user at specific intervals , If the time does not updated for a particular time period then consider it as offline,

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats a very nice answer. Please how do i do an IST timer.

Comment: The solution is :

Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000; String ts = tsLong.toString();
 Please upvote if the solution works actually it is UST I mistakes it for International Standard Time

Comment: I can't find any upvote button.

Comment: Is it worked perfectly

Comment: No,it just giving me errors in Unity, but i will fine tune it.